# Show list of users based on taxonomy term (D7)

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, users

I have a taxonomy vocabulary "Department". In the user account I have a taxonomy term reference field with this vocabulary. So each user can be assigned to one or more departments. I used the module Taxonomy Meny to show the taxonomy terms in my main menu.

Now I want to show a list of users when I click on a department in the menu. Does anybody have an idea how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right Mohammed, I should be using views.
Use a view with a filter on the department field and then create a link to the view page in my main menu.
I was overthinking this way too much.